# Power supply for guitar effects

Tags: guitar, electronics

I recently bought a few guitar effects, and now i want to get myself a good power supply for all of them.

I've read about different parameters and i understand most of them, however what i want to know is what difference does isolation of the the output make.

For example the
[Yankee PS-M1](http://yankee.com.pl/ps-m1-power-supply/?lang=en) has two separate(isolated) sections with 5 outputs each.
I understand that when i use my effects in a FX Loop i need to power them from a separate source. 
Currently i dont use the FX Loop i just use them before the amp.

Would it be wrong to power them from separate outputs?(if i have 7 effects, can i power 4 from one 3 from the other section?)

I'm also thinking about [Gator G-BUS](http://gatorcases.com/products/guitar/pedal-boards-and-stands/g-bus/pedal-board-power-supply-g-bus-8-us/). It doesn't say anything about having isolated outputs.
Does that mean that i shouldn't use it to supply both FX Loop effects and the rest?

Comment: I do not see how this is possibly a non-production question.  It is directly related to the audio production of guitar pedals for performance, which would be live sound reinforcement, which is absolutely on topic and production oriented.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for using isolated power is that variations in the voltage provided may impact the processing of effects, particularly when using analog effects.  Isolated power prevents the power consumption of one effect from impacting the performance of others.

With well designed pedals it is unlikely to matter too much and the impact on decent digital pedals should be pretty much non-existent, but if you notice two pedals interfering with each other, try moving them to different power banks.